# Android Service is creating again and again

Tags: android, android-service

I have a button on which following code is written

```
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

                        cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);

                        Intent intent = new Intent(Formact.this, MyService.class);


                        MyService.pintent = PendingIntent.getService(Formact.this, 0, intent, 0);


                        MyService.alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                                    MyService.alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,cal.getTimeInMillis(), 5000, MyService.pintent);
```

now once the services is created it has to destroy on a specific action but after each time it destroy it starts again.
here is my service class

```
public class MyService extends Service {
public static int counter = 0;
public static PendingIntent pintent;
public static AlarmManager alarm;
 Boolean save=false;
public MyService() {

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return new  Binder() ;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service was Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

    counter++;
    Toast.makeText(this, " Service Started" + "  " + counter, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    SaveForm handler = new SaveForm(getApplicationContext());



    handler.setobj(getApplicationContext());

    handler.setText(Formact.sendform, Formact.listString);

    handler.stratConnection();

    String m = "";
    int val = 0;
    try{
        Log.e("val",SaveForm.msg);
        if(SaveForm.msg!=null)
        {
        m=SaveForm.msg.substring(SaveForm.msg.length() - 1);
        }
        val=Integer.parseInt(m);

        Log.e("val",m);



    if(val>0)
    {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data saved", 100);
        toast.show();
    save=true;
        MyService.this.stopSelf();

    //      alarm.cancel(pintent);



        if(alarm!=null)
        {
            try{
            alarm.cancel(pintent);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Toast toasdst = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Massi", 100);
                toasdst.show();
            }
            alarm=null;
        }       
    }
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Not saved", 100);
        toast.show();
        ///responseStr = responseStrr;
    }

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onDestroy();



    if(save)

    {
        try{


             stopSelf();


        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Head Bang", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            super.onDestroy();
        }
    }

    }
    }
```

I had set the **alarm.cancle** but it throws exception because **alarm** is already **null**

I had also tried this

```
    @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    try{
      //  String parameter = intent.getStringExtra("param_name");
        if(save){
            stopSelf();
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){
    }
    return startId;
}
```

But nothing works service starts again and again.
One more thing if I did not close the application than every thing works perfect the alarm is canceled but when I close the application and expect to run it same it background it start creating again and again.

Help please.

Comment: because you are creating service in repeat mode @setrepeat alarm it will call in every 5 sec aproxx

Comment: Add this : MyService.alarm.cancel(MyService.pintent);

Comment: you are right @koutuk but how can I destroy it

Comment: @HareshChhelana I am already doing this and its not working

Comment: I need to remove that alarm I knew it but how???

Comment: it mean its your Requirement to call service in repeat mode ??

Comment: can i suggest a alternative Solution ?

Comment: Have you tried Timer Class insteadof Alarm simply Create Timer object and call methord schedule(threadobj,repeattime,startafter);

Comment: is the pending intent thread object?? If not than what will be the thread object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64703/discussion-between-syeda-zunairah-and-koutuk).

Comment: it will invoke thread run methord in every x sec until you call timer.cancel();

Comment: Debug at `return startId;`. what's startId? Is it START_STICKY?

Comment: @MysticMagic I am not using public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) any more as it was not working

Comment: should I include it again??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you are storing the data to the server by using

```
 handler.setText(Formact.sendform, Formact.listString);
```

Simply once the data is saved make

```
Formact.sendform=null
 Formact.listString=null
```

when these values are null the application will throw a exception catch it in a catch block and use this line to close

```
    MyService.alarm.cancel(MyService.pintent);
    MyService.this.stopService();
```

service will not start again.

Answer (score 2):

1.Do not use `onStart()`, in docs:

```
onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
This method was deprecated in API level 5. Implement onStartCommand(Intent, int, int) instead.
```

Use `onStartCommand` instead and `return START_NOT_STICKY` or `START_STICKY` not `startId`.
2.  It seems that you are starting a connection `handler.stratConnection();` if you are binding anything to it using `bindService()`, then you need to unbind it from the service using `unbindService(mConnection)`. As given in docs:

```
Disconnect from an application service. You will no longer receive calls as the service is restarted, and the service is now allowed to stop at any time.
```

If you are not binding anything then return `null` in `onBind()`.

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

3. Use `super.onDestroy()` like this:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
super.onDestroy();
/***** No need to put this as it is already going to be destroyed
if(save)

{
    try{


         stopSelf();


    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Head Bang", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}

}
*****/
}
```

4. Cancel the alarm by `alarm.cancel(pintent)` before calling `stopSelf()`.

```
if(alarm!=null)
    {
        try{
        alarm.cancel(pintent);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast toasdst = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Massi", 100);
            toasdst.show();
        }
        alarm=null;
    }
MyService.this.stopSelf();
```

5. You are using `alarm` and `pintent` without initializing it. It is not initialized in your code.
6. Stop service in your activity by using `context.stopService(intent)`, using the same intent as `Intent intent = new Intent(Formact.this, MyService.class);`.